# Calculation of the squared Euclidean norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Just a simple question. I'm reading an article and come across an equation that I cannot replicate as done in the original.

\begin{align}
&\|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\alpha} \|^2 - \|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{\beta}\|^2\\
&= \|\mathbf{x}\| \|\mathbf{x}\| - 2 \|\mathbf{\mathbf{\alpha}}\| \|\mathbf{x}\| + \|\mathbf{\alpha}\| \|\mathbf{\mathbf{\alpha}}\|  - \|\mathbf{x}\| \|\mathbf{x}\| +2 \|\mathbf{\beta}\| \|\mathbf{x}\| - \|\mathbf{\beta}\| \|\mathbf{\beta}\|\\
&= \mathbf{\alpha}^T \mathbf{\alpha} - \beta^T \beta + 2(\sqrt{\mathbf{\beta}\cdot\mathbf{\beta}}-\sqrt{\mathbf{\alpha}\cdot\mathbf{\alpha}})\|\mathbf{x}\|\\
&= \mathbf{\alpha}^T \mathbf{\alpha} - \beta^T \beta + 2(\sqrt{\mathbf{\beta}\cdot\mathbf{\beta}}-\sqrt{\mathbf{\alpha}\cdot\mathbf{\alpha}})(\sqrt{\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}}),
\end{align}
where I used the fact that $$\|a\|\|a\| = \sqrt{a\cdot a}\sqrt{a\cdot a} = \sqrt{a^T a}\sqrt{a^T a} = a^Ta.$$

However, the article gives $$2(\beta-\alpha)^T \mathbf{x} + \alpha^T \alpha - \beta^T\beta $$

Comment: When you write ||a|| ||b|| you see $||a|| ||b||$ but when you write \|a\|\|b\| you see $\|a\|\|b\|$.  It appears that you actually manually added extra space between them after following the first way of coding this.  The second way is standard and as with everything in TeX (and hence in LaTeX and MathJax) the spacing conventions are built in to the software.  I edited the question accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: $$ \| \mathbf{x} -\alpha\|^2 = (\mathbf{x}-\alpha)(\mathbf{x} - \alpha)^T $$ $$ = \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T - \mathbf{x}\alpha^T - \alpha\mathbf{x}^T + \alpha\alpha^T $$ $$ = \|x\|^2 - 2\mathbf{x}\cdot\alpha + \|\alpha\|^2. $$ Thus you have $\|\mathbf{x}\|\|\alpha\|$ where you need $\mathbf{x}\cdot\alpha$. Those two are not the same. $\qquad$

Comment: Even if it $\mathbf{x}$ is a matrix, can we say $\mathbf{x}\alpha^T=\alpha\mathbf{x}^T$? How?

Comment: @MichaelHardy And what happen when both are matrices? $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^T  = \mathbf{y}\mathbf{x}^T$ ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends on what kind of matrix norm you're using.  Suppose you say $\|A\| = \sqrt{ \operatorname{trace}(A A^T) }$ for $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$.  I think you can check that makes $A\mapsto \|A\|$ a norm. And for $A,B\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ you can easily show that $ \operatorname{trace}(AB) = \operatorname{trace}(BA)$.  Then you have $$ \|A-B\|^2 = \operatorname{trace}((A - B)(A- B)^T) = \operatorname{trace}( AA^T - AB^T - BA^T + BB^t ) $$ $$ = \operatorname{trace}(AA^T) - \operatorname{trace}(AB^T) - \operatorname{trace}(BA^T) + \operatorname{trace}(BB^T) = \cdots\cdots $$

Comment: $$ = \|A\|^2 - \operatorname{trace}(AB^T) - \operatorname{trace}(BA^T) + \|B\|^2. $$ $$ = \|A\|^2 - 2\operatorname{trace}(AB^T) + \|B\|^2 $$  See if you can show that $(A,B) \mapsto \operatorname{trace}(AB^T)$ is an inner product. $\qquad$

Comment: On the other hand there's another commonly used norm: $$ \|A\| = \sup_{\mathbb x} \frac{\|A\mathbb x\|}{\|\mathbb x\|}. $$  If I'm not mistaken, that one does not come from any inner product.  If you can show it fails to satisfy the parallelogram law, that will establish that it doesn't come from any inner product. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transition from the first line to the second is incorrect.  We should have
$$
\|x - \alpha\|^2 - \|x - \beta\|^2 = \\
(x - \alpha)^T(x - \alpha) - (x - \beta)^T(x - \beta) = \\
\|x\|^2 + \|\alpha\|^2 - \|x\|^2 - \|\beta\|^2 - x^T\alpha - \alpha^Tx + x^T\beta + \beta^Tx =\\
\|\alpha\|^2 - \|\beta\|^2 - 2\alpha^Tx + 2 \beta^Tx =\\
\alpha^T\alpha - \beta^T\beta + 2(\beta - \alpha)^Tx
$$
which is the desired result.

Comment: Your second line is the correct expansion of 
$$
(\|x\| - \|\alpha\|)^2 - (\|x\| - \|\beta\|)^2
$$

Comment: Note of course that for any vectors $u,v$ we have $u^Tv = v^Tu$.

Comment: Thanks. One follow-up question: in your answer, how can I get from the second line to the third?

Comment: I'm using the distributive property of the dot product ("FOIL"ing it out).  So, for example,
$$
(x - \alpha)^T(x - \alpha) = \\
x^Tx - x^T\alpha - \alpha^Tx + \alpha^T\alpha
$$
(which I have reorganized in the next line)